# Unable to mount oracle instance

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I am trying to shutdown the system, then I want to mount it. I have tried this:

```
SQL> shutdown immediate;
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> startup mount;
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
SQL> startup mount;
ORA-24324: service handle not initialized
ORA-01041: internal error. hostdef extension doesn't exist
```

I have googled for solution but I can't found the exact reason that causes it to go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Exit sqlplus.

Make sure your os user is part of the DBA group (ORA_DBA in Windows).

Make sure ORACLE_SID is set to the SID of the database and unset TWO_TASK:

Windows:

```
set ORACLE_SID=ORCL
set TWO_TASK=
```

or

Unix/Linux

```
ORACLE_SID=ORCL
TWO_TASK=
export TWO_TASK
```

Now, connect as sysdba:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Now, startup the database:

```
SQL> startup mount;

SQL> alter database open;
```

Answer (score 0):

set ORACLE_SID=database

set TWO_TASK=

sqlplus /nolog

CONNECT /@database as sysdba

startup

Comment: You should describe why this works.

Answer (score -2):

Once you have closed the database, you need to reconnect

Comment: How can i reconnect. when database is shutdown.

Comment: @madhu I think steve meant, close sqlplus and relaunch.